# Would the term "guy" to refer to a man be used in the "30s?

Tags: slang

I'm writing a story that takes place in 1940. Would the dialog include the word guy to refer to a man?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You would do best to cite some research you have done prior to asking a question. Please show somew effort to find the answer on your own. Thanks.

Comment: You can search Google books (rather than straight Google) for *guy* or *the guy* or *was a guy* (common combinations) and sort the results by date.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *guy* has been used in this manner much earlier than the 30s. The earliest citation in the OED is this:

> I can't tonight, for I am going to be seduced by a rich old **Guy**.
>   <sub>*Swell's Night Guide*, 1847</sub>

And here's an example from the 30s:

> These are the **guys** that find the world forlorn And wish (correctly) they had not been born.
>   <sub>*Georgiad*, 1931</sub>

Answer (score 0):

http://www.etymonline.com/word/guy

> guy (n.2)
>   **"fellow," 1847, American English;** earlier, in British English (1836) "grotesquely or poorly dressed person," originally (1806) "effigy of Guy Fawkes," leader of the Gunpowder Plot to blow up British king and Parliament (Nov. 5, 1605). The effigies were paraded through the streets by children on the anniversary of the conspiracy. The male proper name is from French, related to Italian Guido.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any quotes from mid 19th c that express this usage of 'guy'?

Comment: W.S. Gilbert has Ko-ko in 'The Mikado' (1885) sing about 'The lady from the provinces who dresses like a guy, and who "doesn't think she dances, but would rather like to try".' I take it to mean that she dresses grotesquely, not like a man. Incidentally, Guy Fawkes was _not_ the leader of the Gunpowder Plot, just the one who was caught with the powder!